# If the first operand of an additive expression is convertible to both pointer and integer, which conversion is chosen?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overloading, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

In the following example, which conversion function should be called? Why should that one be chosen over the other?

```
struct A
{
  operator int();
  operator int*();
};

A x;
int i = x + 1;
```

The compiler chooses `operator int()`.. but why?

Here are some relevant quotes from C++03:

From [expr.add]

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or enumeration type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a completely defined object type and the other shall have integral or enumeration type.

From [conv]

> expressions with a given type will be implicitly converted to other types in several contexts:
>
> - When used as operands of operators. The operator’s requirements for its operands dictate the destination type

Comment: I would argue that this should be ambiguous. I don't *think* non-pointers are any more special.

Comment: Does it call the other one if you say `int *i = x + 1;`?

Comment: @John, No, it just complains about `int -> int *`.

Comment: Well, I did a quick skim through § 13.3.3.2 (**Ranking implicit conversion sequences**) and didn't see anything in particular that relates to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that the built-in operator which accepts a pointer as its left hand operand accepts an object of type `std::ptrdiff_t` as its right hand operand. This is specified in § 13.6 of the C++11 Standard:

> For every cv-qualified or cv-unqualified object type T there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> T * operator+(T *, std::ptrdiff_t);
> ```
>
> [...]

Since `1` has type `int`, the compiler considers the built-in `operator +` that takes two `int`s as a better choice, because it onlys require a (user-defined) conversion for the first argument.

If you provided an argument of type `std::ptrdiff_t` as the right hand operand of `operator +`, you would see the expected ambiguity:

```
int i = x + static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(1); // AMBIGUOUS!
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=92ec60d6c6eb63ba29c46d0429b7e0a5-4610ec02f09472fe886fb7fc4894b294).

Comment: Good call. Where is it specified that overload resolution should be used in this scenario?

Comment: @willj: I just switched off my laptop and I'm writing from my mobile, so I can't tell the exact paragraph number, but it's somewhere in clause 13. I'd suggest searching for occurrences of "operator" in that clause, should not be hard to find

Comment: 13.6 starts out "The candidate operator functions that represent the built-in operators defined in Clause 5 are specified in
this subclause. These candidate functions participate in the operator overload resolution process as described
in 13.3.1.2 and are used for no other purpose."

Comment: [over.match.oper] If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration, a user-defined operator function might be
declared that implements this operator or a user-defined conversion can be necessary to convert the operand
to a type that is appropriate for a built-in operator. In this case, overload resolution is used to determine
which operator function or built-in operator is to be invoked to implement the operator.